# How to defer parsing of javascript of W3 Total Cache's cached & minified javascript file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, caching, w3-total-cache

How to defer parsing of JavaScript of W3 Total Cache's cached & minified JavaScript file. [For Example](http://www.example.com/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/MAvyUgtSq0ozk89OLsrPycnMS9fNSyzTMUCTTos0MvNzEOVLc7JTM6GkCBJAA.js)